# Transistor not totally acting like a switch

Tags: voltage, transistors

I have made two different circuits that, to my knowledge, should give the same result if the transistor is acting like a switch.

The current "passes" through the first switch/transistor and "passes" through the last switch/transistor before going to ground.

Circuit with switches:

[image]

Circuit with transistors:

[image]

I am not getting the same voltage going across the resistors.

I am under the impression that it has something to do with the battery powering the transistors, but I am not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Hi, sorry I can't follow/decode/decipher your wiring diagram.  If you could draw a schematic, you might get more and better responses to your question; and in the process of drawing the schematic you'll probably better understand the essence of the circuit.  For example, I cannot tell if the transistors you used are MOSFETs or BJTs; and even if I were to correctly guess at them being NPN, I can't tell if the particular one you chose has a C-B-E or E-B-C pinout.

Comment: Welcome! Please click on edit and the schematic symbol. From there you can draw a schematic, the _de facto_ language of EEs around the world.

Comment: May l know the value of beta you used in the design calculations

Comment: @DanielChisholm If you look carefully, the transistors have "N" written on them (presumably meaning NPN), and if you look even more carefully the individual pins are labeled C, B, and E. It's a poor replacement for a schematic, but *technically* the information is there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the circuit you have (leaving out the transistors that aren't being driven)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSA0hp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Look at the biasing for Q1. 3.3 V goes through R1 and into the base, the emitter then has two 1k resistors and another transistor between it and ground, so the base voltage will have to be higher than the voltage drops across those. What would happen if the voltage across the two resistors was 12 V like in the mechanical switch version? The base of Q1 would need to be at 12 V + 0.7 V + Q2's Vce. You're not going to get that out of the 3.0 V battery. What you'll get is roughly 3.0 V - 0.7 V = 2.3 V, which is what you're showing.

So while Q2 is getting fully switched on, Q1 is not.

One thing you could try is change Q1 to a PNP transistor with it's emitter to +12 V and add an inverting driver something like this:
[image]

Comment: Masterfully decoded schematic... Looks like some sort of TTL stage with dynamic load...